# SQL Replace Using Join with Like

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL 2008.

tblComments is a data table that stores user comments.
tblErrorNumbers is a lookup table that has a finite list of errors and their associated description. Couple examples:

```
Error Number | Error Description
100          | Unreadable  
200          | Printer Error
```

I have been asked to find all references to error numbers in the comments field and replace them with the error description.  So, for example, replace

```
Blah 100 Blah
```

with

```
Blah Unreadable Blah
```

What I have below works only as long as there is only one error number match in the table.  But... if I have this:

```
Blah 100 Blah 200 Blah
```

The result set is:

```
Blah 100 Blah Printer Error Blah
```

Why does this happen??  What can I do to replace ALL references of the number with the description?  Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

SQL:

```
select 

a.comments as originalString,
REPLACE (a.comments, b.errorNumber, b.errorDescription) As newString


from tblComments a

Left Join tblErrorNumbers b ON a.comments LIKE '%' + b.errorNumber + '%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, the `replace()` only works on one comment at a time.  And, they are not nested.  Each is replaced independently.

One solution is to use recursive CTEs for this.  I think the following should give an example of how to do this:

```
with ErrorNumbers as (
      select row_number() over (order by ErrorNumber) as seqnum, en.*
      from tblErrorNumbers en
     ),
     cte as (
      select replace(c.comments, en.errorNumber, en.errorDescription) as comments,
             1 as seqnum,
             (select max(seqnum) from ErrorNumbers) as maxseqnum
      from tblComments c left outer join
           ErrorNumbers en
           on en.seqnum = 1
      union all
      select replace(cte.comments, en.errorNumber, en.errorDescription) as comments, 
             cte.seqnum + 1, cte.maxseqnum
      from cte join
           ErrorNumbers en
           on en.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
      where cte.seqnum <= cte.maxseqnum
     )
select distinct comments
from cte;
```

Comment: I ran this, but I got this error:  "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."  Not sure what that means?

Comment: @baldwingrand . . . If you set up a SQL Fiddle (SQLFiddle) with your data structures and some data, then I'll make this work.

Comment: I've added this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c46e/1  I haven't used SQLFiddle before; hopefully you can see it.  The error is, however, not appearing.  My actual data has about 3000 records, so maybe the size is an issue.  I don't believe i can insert that many into SQL Fiddle.  In the SQLFiddle, however, only 3 records are returning.  Again, could be my inexperience with it.

Comment: @baldwingrand . . . SQL Fiddle is really great.  The error was pretty small -- the first part of the recursive CTE ended up making most of the comments `NULL` because of the `like` condition.  I just removed that and it now seems to be working.